# What is the mongo connection uri in circle ci?

Tags: mongodb, circleci

I'm running mongo on circle ci and it seems like everything is connected fine, however the application hangs and never connects to the DB.

Here's the `config.yml`

```
version: 2.1

orbs:
  node: circleci/node@5.0.2
  nx: nrwl/nx@1.5.1

commands:
  bt-setup:
    steps:
      - checkout
      - bt-yarn-install

  bt-mongo:
    steps:
      - run:
          name: MongoDB Install
          command: |
            sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 9DA31620334BD75D9DCB49F368818C72E52529D4
            echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list
            sudo apt-get update
            sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org-shell
      - setup_remote_docker:
          version: 20.10.14
      - run:
          name: Dockerize Mongo
          command: dockerize -wait tcp://localhost:27017 -timeout 1m
      - run:
          name: Get versions
          command: |
            node -v
            npm -v
            mongo --version
            mongo localhost --eval "db.version()"
      - run:
          name: Connect to DB
          command: mongo --eval "printjson(db.apikeys.count());" localhost

  bt-yarn-install:
    steps:
      - node/install-packages:
          pkg-manager: yarn

jobs:
  test-api:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/node:lts-browsers
      - image: mongo:4.4.14
    environment:
      NX_CLOUD_DISTRIBUTED_EXECUTION: "true"
    steps:
      - bt-setup
      - bt-mongo
      - run:
          name: Run Tests
          command: |
            MONGODB_URI=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/localhost IS_CI_TEST=true yarn test:api --run-in-band
      - bt-nx-stop

workflows:
  build:
    jobs:
      - test-api
```

And the output:

```
$ node -v
v16.16.0

$ npm -v
8.11.0

$ mongo --version
MongoDB shell version v4.0.28
git version: af1a9dc12adcfa83cc19571cb3faba26eeddac92
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: none
build environment:
    distmod: ubuntu1804
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64

$ mongo localhost --eval "db.version()"
MongoDB shell version v4.0.28
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/localhost?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("ceab1ceb-c061-4be2-bc34-ef72f67331d5") }
MongoDB server version: 4.4.14
WARNING: shell and server versions do not match
4.4.14
```

any ideas what's going on?
Is my connection string url correct?

```
MONGODB_URI=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/localhost
```

Comment: Why are you trying to spin up Mongo in the primary container, rather than use the `mongo:4.4.14` you're starting in parallel?

Comment: I pretty much tried everything I could think of. What do you suggest I will hange/try @jonrsharpe